# how would I achieve this in mustache.js?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, mustache

I have the following js object:

```
var user = 
{
   FirstName:'John',
   MiddleName:'Jacob',
   LastName:'Smith',
}
```

I want to use mustache.js to display this info in an html table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>{{FirstName}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{MiddleName}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{LastName}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, if the js object doesn't have a MiddleName value then the MiddleName row of the template shouldn't display because there is no MiddleName value to display.  How would you structure your mustache template to accommodate this scenario?

Comment: `mustacheJS` is logicless. It will render the the view as you have defined it - I think you would have to use JS to hide the `<td>` if the object does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

So you would do it this way:

```
{{#.}}
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>{{FirstName}}</td>
  </tr>
  {{#MiddleName}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{MiddleName}}</td>
  </tr>
  {{/MiddleName}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{LastName}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
{{/.}}
```

Where  `{{#somekey}}{{/somekey}}` is executed only if that `somekey` is present